# Authorize GMail API with JWT

Tags: google-api, jwt, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm trying to send an email through the gmail API from a Node.js application. I had this working, following the documentation and using the node-mailer package. However, I noticed that when we change our organizations password, the connection is no longer good (which makes sense). I'm therefore trying to authorize with a JWT instead.

The JWT is correctly generated and posted to `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`. This request then returns an access_token.

When it comes time to write and send the email, I tried to simply adapt the code that was previously working (at the time with a client_secret, client_id and redirect_uris):

```
const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: access_token });
  gmail.users.messages.send(
    {
      userId: 'email',
      resource: {
        raw: encodedMessage
      }
    },
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log('NODEMAILER - The API returned: ' + err);
      }

      console.log(
        'NODEMAILER  Sending email reply from server: ' + result.data
      );
    }
  );
```

The API keeps returning `Error: Login Required`.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

**EDIT**

I've modified my code and autehntication to add the client_id and client_secret:

```
const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      credentials.gmail.client_id,
      credentials.gmail.client_secret,
      credentials.gmail.redirect_uris[0]
    );

    oAuth2Client.credentials = {
      access_token: access_token
    };
    const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: oAuth2Client });
    gmail.users.messages.send(
      {
        userId: 'email',
        resource: {
          raw: encodedMessage
        }
      },
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return console.log('NODEMAILER - The API returned: ' + err);
        }

        console.log(
          'NODEMAILER  Sending email reply from server: ' + result.data
        );
      }
    );
```

But now the error is even less precise: `Error: Bad Request`

Comment: Could you maybe share more information about your actual request? Is this failing before getting the access token, or after? What scopes are you using? Could I maybe suggest to look into the [README.md of the official Node.js library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client)

Comment: Hi @Raserhin, This is only failing when the email tries to send (gmail.users.messages.send). The access_token is properly generated and the only scope being used is www.googleapis/auth/gmail.send. I believe it might have to do with needing to use a service account? I need this integration to always work automatically, no user authorization.

Comment: How are you authenticating your service account? As far as I know service account cannot use Gmail if they don't use domain wide delegation (imagine all the spam that could make). Are you using domain wide delegation? In case you are unfamiliar with the topic you can read [some information here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) or [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation). Are you actually trying to impersonate an user from your domain?

Comment: I actually found the problem. For some reason, setting the userId as the email to be impersonated wasn't working, however setting it as 'me' worked like a charm

Comment: I'm confused though, are you using the credentials of your account or the service account one? Also please remember to post your solution as an answer so other people could benefit from that.

Comment: I'm authorizing with the service account, acting in the name of the gmail user account (having granted delegated access to the endpoint for sending emails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the final authorization code that worked for me:

```
var credentials = require('../../credentials');
    const privKey = credentials.gmail.priv_key.private_key;

    var jwtParams = {
      iss: credentials.gmail.priv_key.client_email,
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send',
      aud: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
      exp: Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000 + 120),
      iat: Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000),
      sub: [INSERT EMAIL THAT WILL BE SENDING (not the service email, the one that has granted delegated access to the service account)]
    };

    var gmail_token = jwt.sign(jwtParams, privKey, {
      algorithm: 'RS256'
    });

    var params = {
      grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
      assertion: gmail_token
    };

    var params_string = querystring.stringify(params);

    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
      data: params_string,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }).then(response => {
      let mail = new mailComposer({
        to: [ARRAY OF RECIPIENTS],
        text: [MESSAGE CONTENT],
        subject: subject,
        textEncoding: 'base64'
      });

      mail.compile().build((err, msg) => {
        if (err) {
          return console.log('Error compiling mail: ' + err);
        }

        const encodedMessage = Buffer.from(msg)
          .toString('base64')
          .replace(/\+/g, '-')
          .replace(/\//g, '_')
          .replace(/=+$/, '');

        sendMail(encodedMessage, response.data.access_token, credentials);
      });
    });
```

So that code segment above uses a private key to create a JSON Web Token (JWT), where: iss is the service account to be used, scope is the endpoint of the gmail API being accessed (this must be preauthorized), aud is the google API oAuth2 endpoint, exp is the expiration time, iat is the time created and sub is the email the service account is acting for.

The token is then signed and a POST request is made to the Google oAuth2 endpoint. On success, I use the mailComposer component of NodeMailer to build the email, with an array of recipients, a message, a subject and an encoding. That message is then encoded.

And here's my `sendMail()` function:

```
const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      credentials.gmail.client_id,
      credentials.gmail.client_secret,
      credentials.gmail.redirect_uris[0]
    );

    oAuth2Client.credentials = {
      access_token: access_token
    };

    const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: oAuth2Client });
    gmail.users.messages.send(
      {
        userId: 'me',
        resource: {
          raw: encodedMessage
        }
      },
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return console.log('NODEMAILER - The API returned: ' + err);
        }

        console.log(
          'NODEMAILER  Sending email reply from server: ' + result.data
        );
      }
    );
```

In this function, I am creating a new googleapis OAuth2 object using the credentials of the service account (here stored in an external file for added security). I then pass in the access_token (generated in the auth script with the JWT). The message is then sent.

**Pay attention to the `userId: 'me'` in the `sendMail()` function, this was critical for me.**

Comment: Thank you, @Phil! I have spent a few days to find, how to exchange GTW for ID token, but it does not look to exist in the official docs.

Comment: @AlexandrPriezzhev I posted below how to only use the googleapis package + service-account key

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I was able to only use `googleapis` package instead of axios + googleapis with your service account. You will need domain wide authority for this account with the scope used below associated with it. Follow this to do that https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en

You can also use the mailComposer example up above to create the email. keys is the service_credentials.json file you get when making this service account

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"];
const client = new google.auth.JWT({
    email: keys.client_email,
    key: keys.private_key,
    scopes: scope,
    subject: "emailToSendFrom@something.com",
});

await client.authorize();

const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: client});

const subject = ' Hello ';
const utf8Subject = `=?utf-8?B?${Buffer.from(subject).toString('base64')}?=`;
const messageParts = [
    'From: Someone <emailToSendFrom@something.com>',//same email as above
    'To: Someone <whoever@whoever.com>',
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8',
    'MIME-Version: 1.0',
    `Subject: ${utf8Subject}`,
    '',
    'This is a message just to say hello.',
    'So... <b>Hello!</b>  ❤️',
];
const message = messageParts.join('\n');

    // The body needs to be base64url encoded.
const encodedMessage = Buffer.from(message)
    .toString('base64')
    .replace(/\+/g, '-')
    .replace(/\//g, '_')
    .replace(/=+$/, '');

const res = await gmail.users.messages.send({
    userId: 'me',
    requestBody: {
        raw: encodedMessage,
    },
});
console.log(res.data);
```